# Как определить границу субмеша в шейдере?

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

Вводные unity3d. шейдер.
есть меш с кучей субмешей.
У каждого субмеша есть цвет и допустим что нет текстуры.

Как определить что у текущей точки и у одной из соседних точек цвет отличается?
Либо как определить что соседняя точка относится к другому субмешу.
Либо иной способ определить что эта точка пограничная в субмеше.

Нужно все субмеши обвести контуром. Интересна любая зацепка.

Comment: Это случаем не проблема XY? Зачем определять, отличается ли цвет соседних точек?

Comment: Дабы границу у субмеша нарисовать. Не обязательно цвет. Любой способ понять, что точка - граничная.

Comment: Ну тогда так и пишите в вопросе.

Comment: я так и написал. либо-либо.